# Adding number and Symbols in Django

Tags: python, django, forms, validation

How can I define a field that accepts Float percentage numbers? e.g 8.4%

I have defined the field as such but it doesn't do the job. Any ideas?

```
alphanumeric = RegexValidator(r'^[0-9%]+$', 'Only alphanumeric characters are allowed.')    
add_on_percentage = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True, null=True, validators=[alphanumeric])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use validators in your model and add the percentage in your template when you are displaying the numbers. This allows you to do any manipulations easily.

```
from django.core.validators import MaxValueValidator, MinValueValidator
    #in your model..
    percentage = models.FloatField(
        validators = [
            MinValueValidator(0.0), MaxValueValidator(100.0)
    ])
```

Comment: How do you mean "add percentage in my template"

Comment: @k19Uch I mean add the percentage symbol in your template. For example, in a template do `{{ percentage }}&#38`. If the value of `percentage` is `8.4` it will be displayed as "8.4%". And if you want to, say add 5 percent more to an existing value, you can easily do it as it is just a floatfield.

Answer (score 0):

If you want only float numbers with percent symbol saved in database, this regex `^\d+.\d+%+$` will do the job.
NOTE: by default validation on fields will work only with usage in ModelForm.
If you want to check it every time, override `save` in your class in this way:

```
    def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False, using=None,
         update_fields=None):
    self.full_clean()
    return super(YourModel, self).save(force_insert=force_insert, force_update=force_update,
                                   using=using, update_fields=update_fields)
```